# Only getting 1 button from 4 Enum values, Why?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I need to generate the Enum values as radio buttons as below, but for one prop of 4,5 values am only getting a groupbox with 1 button, item1. where am I wrong ?

```
private void CreateButton(List<object> prop) 
{
    GroupBox gb = new GroupBox();
    gb.Location = new Point(locationX, nextLocationY);
    gb.Name = "groupBox" + countControls;
    gb.Text = "some object";
    countControls++;
    foreach (var p in pr) 
    {
        ObjectType pType = p.Type;
        if (pType is Enum) 
        { 
            var TypesArray = Enumerable.ToArray(((Enum)pType).Values);
            foreach (var enumType in TypesArray) 
            {
                radioButtonY = 10;
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
                rb.Width = rbWidth;
                rb.Height = rbHeight;
                rb.Name = enumType.Name + countControls;
                rb.Text = enumType.Name;
                countControls++;
                rb.Location = new Point(radioButtonX, radioButtonY);
                radioButtonY += rbHeight;

                gb.Controls.Add(rb);

                rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    gb.Height = 5 * rbHeight + 20;
    gb.Width = rbWidth + 20;
    nextLocationY += gb.Height + MARGIN;
    Controls.Add(gb);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need this line

```
radioButtonY = 10;
```

to be out of the inner loop, otherwise you get always the same Y value and your buttons are stacked together

```
radioButtonY = 10;
foreach (var enumType in TypesArray) {
   .....
   radioButtonY += rbHeight;

}
```

Comment: nice, thanks. Any suggestion on how to make this display neatly ? maybe the buttons horizontally and the new groupboxes always right below them ? am trying but not fully getting there, they appear messy

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the enum texts and how many groupboxes and radiobutton this code is expected to create.

Comment: well am using the gb.Width,height and buttons too. but somehow I seem to be placing them in the wrong places coz the output is random. Also since this is at runtime, I used Controls.Clear at the top there, so everytime a new object is fed it repopulate the data. but seems wrong coz now everything disappears when I move to next objects at runtime